# Manually bootstrapping application is blocking $rootScope.$emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a mother application with 2 small applications.Earlier my application B was inside my application A. I was bootstrapping application A using ng-app and not manually. This resulted application B not functioning correctly. It was something like this:

```
<html ng-app='A'>
<div id="B"> <-- This app was being manually bootstrapped
</div>
<div>
</div>
</html>
```

Now to resolve application B I manually bootstrapped both applications:

```
<html>
<div id="B"> <-- This app was being manually bootstrapped
</div>
<div id="A"> <-- Now this is also being manually bootstrapped
</div>
</html>
```

The issue that I am facing is that as soon as I do this all the $rootScope.$emit stop working. Nothing comes up in the console and I am totally confused what can be the root cause and how I can resolve this?

Note: I have reverted my code to earlier code and found that it is working when I use ng-app.

Comment: curious why you can't just inject the second app main module into the first

Comment: AngularJS won't work with two `$rootScope`s on the window. Re-factor your design to use only one `$RootScope`. (You can make modules dependencies of other modules.)